# Qt5 - Fatal:Qt: INTERNALL ERROR: failed to install GetMessage hook

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I am using Qt5 on windows7. I have desktop application which is server/client kind of application. Application calls http request and get data from server. My application has polling mechanism which calls one http method to check server is available or not. It does this every 5 second. Now issue is when in midnight server gets restarted my application goes offline and then come online mode. In this case after few hours I get error message as follows :

```
Fatal:Qt: INTERNALL ERROR: failed to install GetMessage hook
```

I am not sure why this error comes and there is no detail on that. I am using qDebug to print logs and I found above error information from that log. Let me know if anyone has idea about this error.

Comment: In my experience (we had this problem in our server windows 2003 as well running wkhtmltopdf.exe from coldfusion/railo), the problem could be running too many parallel instances / reports at the same time. check for hanging frozen processes in the task manager or logs.

Comment: @Premal: Could you find the reason/solution for this problem?